# borrar contacto de Agenda c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema:

Quiero eliminar el contacto buscado, pero siempre elimina el primer contacto registrado.
Esta es la class de la agenda:

```
 class agenda
{
public:
    char nombre[35], dom[50], tel[20], cor[30];
    void Capturar();
    void Mostrar();
    void Buscar();
    void Modificar();
    void Eliminar();
}trabajadores[10];
```

Este es el codigo de la funcion:

```
int bandera,i,contador;
char buscado[35];  
void agenda::Eliminar()
{
    int i,j;
    bandera = 1;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buscado,nombre)==0)
        {
            trabajadores[i] = trabajadores[i+1];
            for(j=0; j < contador; j++)
            {
                trabajadores[i].Buscar();
                trabajadores[j] = trabajadores[j+1];
            }//fin de for
            j--;
            contador--;
        }//fin de if    
    }//fin del for
 }
```

Y asi lo mando a llamar:

```
case 5:
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\n Nombre de persona a buscar para eliminar:";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(buscado,35);
            cout<<"contador"<<contador;
            for(i=0;i<contador;i++)
            {
                trabajadores[i].Eliminar();
            }
            if(bandera==0)
            {
                cout<<"\n NO EXISTE PERSONA BUSCADA.";
            }
            cout<<endl;
            system("pause");
            break;
```

El contador aumenta una vez guardado el contacto.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que les comento:
[image: imagen1]

[image: todos]

[image: a eliminar]

[image: elimandos]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Falta demasiado código para darte una respuesta acertada. ¿Cómo defines `trabajadores`? Si es un array de reserva estática como parece, no puedes eliminar elementos a menos que soportes que el hueco va a mantenerse o que muevas el resto de elementos una posición hacia delante. ¿Qué es `contador`, que andas decrementándolo? ¿para qué decrementas `j` si al entrar en el `for` siempre se inicializa a 0? ¿qué es `nombre' y quién lo setea? Intenta acotar tu problema incluyendo el código relacionado con el problema.

Comment: @SuperG280 lo se . pero si pongo todo el codigo no me deja guardar la pregunta.

Comment: No tienes que subir todo el código que tengas, pero sí todo lo que esté relacionado con tu pregunta. Si te falla borrar un elemento del array, vamos a necesitar saber qué y cómo guardas en ese array, como poco.

Comment: @SuperG280 ya agregue el codigo faltante. espero sea util.